# The security token included in the request is invalid. Aws::SQS::Errors::InvalidClientTokenId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, shoryuken

When i try to start shoryuken i am getting this error

The security token included in the request is invalid. (Aws::SQS::Errors::InvalidClientTokenId). Even that is worked for me previously.

The message added to the queue but the Worker not able to access the queue.

Comment: i run a production rails ec2 application, which uses shoryuken as a sqs worker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i fixed this issue. i have to run shoryuken in production mode i have two different keys. Thanks.

```
RAILS_ENV=production  bundle exec shoryuken -R -C config/shoryuken.yml -L ./log/shoryuken.log -P ./log/shoryuken.pid -d
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a new token.
It has probably expired.

Comment: no my key is working all other services like sns and all working only i have problem with sqs with shoryuken